How to import react components from running vite dev into other web app
I want to write a component library in React and use it in a legacy app, but I want to be able to see code changes in the React code when I refresh the page.
Project A: A legacy web server that is serving html/js/css files.
Project B: A new vite react app that is running via "vite dev" in development mode (so that changes are reflected upon page refresh without restarting the vite server)
I now want to include React components from the running vite react server in dev mode.
In Project A I have included the module from Project B via:
<script type="module" crossorigin="" src="http://127.0.0.1:5173/src/main.jsx"></script>

But when I open my Project A in the Browser I see:
Uncaught Error: @vitejs/plugin-react can't detect preamble. Something is wrong. See https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-react/pull/11#discussion_r430879201
    <anonymous> App.jsx:1
App.jsx:1:32
    <anonym> App.jsx:1

What is going on? Is the problem that App.jsx now wants to import react via
import { useState } from 'react'

but cannot find the module react as it only exists in Project B?
Is it possible to create something like a bundle on-the-fly everything the React source changes? That way maybe I can bundle all dependencies?
What would you do if you wanted to use single React components in a legacy web app?
Thank you for reading <3
